# How to automate outlook when there is more than one account configured?

Tags: vbscript, outlook, hp-uft

In my microsoft outlook...I have more than one account configured.. When I try to automate the customised  mailbox(account). It always points to the default inbox... How to change this to the customised inbox I want?

We tried to use the below code:

But always it points to the mailbox  XXXXX@medtronic.com and Inbox folder (The 2nd mailbox)

But we need to point to the Inbox of the RS mailbox and search for the email through VBscript as highlighted below in yellow colour.

```
enter code here

Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`enter code here`
Set objNameSpace = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objSyncs = objNameSpace.SyncObjects
Set myFolder = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
Set ObjMails = myFolder.Items 
Set objFilter = ObjMails[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What points to the default mailbox? `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`? You really need to provide the relevant snippets of your code.

If you want to work with a delegate folder, use either `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder`, or, if the store is already opened in the active profile, retrieve the `Store` object from `Namespace.Stores` collection and use `Store.GetDefaultFolder`.

Comment: HI thanks for your reply, please see my post now,i hacve added the used code snippet

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above, use Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder or Store.GetDefaultFolder

Comment: May I know what parameters I need to pass for Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder,also I have attached the image

Comment: Call Namespace.CreateRecipient and pass the returned Recipient object to GetSharedDefaultFolder .